# How can I populate two columns in a table with different foreach iterations in php/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hey everyone I'm struggling with a problem to display some data. I have two arrays of teams called **rosterWhite** and **rosterBlack**

On my view I have a table with two columns "White" and "Black".

To illustrate, these are my teams int he Controller:

```
$rosterWhite=Roster::where([['match', '=', $id], ['team', '=', 'w']])->get();
$rosterBlack=Roster::where([['match', '=', $id], ['equipo', '=', 'b']])->get();
```

And this is my table in the view:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="rosterTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center">White</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Black</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            @foreach ($rosterWhite as $whitePlayer)
                                            {{ $whitePlayer->nickname }} <br>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            @foreach ($rosterBlack as $blackPlayer)
                                            {{ $blackPlayer->nickname }} <br>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

As you can see, the current implementation will go through the array creating a list of the nicknames inside a single cell and using line jumps.

```
+-------+-------+
| White | Black |
+-------+-------+
|  Wh1  |  Bl1  |
|  Wh2  |  Bl2  |
|  Wh3  |  Bl3  |
|  Wh4  |  Bl4  |
|  Wh5  |  Bl5  |
+-------+-------+
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I iterate through arrays, but instead of filling in everything in a single cell, that each name is a row.

something like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| White | Black |
+-------+-------+
|  Wh1  |  Bl1  |
+-------+-------+
|  Wh2  |  Bl2  |
+-------+-------+
|  Wh3  |  Bl3  |
+-------+-------+
|  Wh4  |  Bl4  |
+-------+-------+
|  Wh5  |  Bl5  |
+-------+-------+
```

Iterating outside of the TD, creates the list horizontally. So each name in a single cell but all names from both teams in the same row.

I can't find a way to iterate through white list, and add cells under White column, then iterate through black list and add names under Black column.

Any tips for this? Maybe I should create two different tables that are somehow connected? thanks!

Comment: I think you're going to have to combine the two arrays together somehow where you can reiterate through rosters and then output something like this @foreach rosters as roster <tr><td>{{$roster->white}}</td><td>{{$roster->black}}</td></tr>@endforeach

Comment: Would the no of white records always equal the no of black records?

Comment: Not necessarily @user3532758. Sometimes there are subs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

In your controller:

```
$rosterWhite=Roster::where([['match', '=', $id], ['team', '=', 'w']])->get();
$rosterBlack=Roster::where([['match', '=', $id], ['equipo', '=', 'b']])->get();
$maxCount = max($rosterWhite->count(), $roasterBlack->count());
```

In your view:

```
...
<tbody>
  @for($i=0;$i<$maxCount;$i++)
  <tr>
       <td class="text-center"> 
       @if( Arr::exists($rosterWhite, $i) ) 
         {{ $rosterWhite[$i]->nickname }} 
       @endif
       </td>
       <td class="text-center"> 
       @if( Arr::exists($rosterBlack, $i) )
         {{ $rosterBlack[$i]->nickname }} 
       @endif 
       </td>
  </tr>
  @endfor
</tbody>
```

And if you want to replace the `@if` condition checking array key existence, you could easily do this:

```
<td class="text-center"> 
    {{ $rosterWhite[$i]->nickname ?? "" }} 
</td>
```

Comment: Clean and simple, and it even accounts for different roster sizes. The only thing I changed is @for($i=0;$i<=$maxCount;$i++) for @for($i=0;$i<$maxCount;$i++) cause I was getting an extra empty row. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that `=` was a mistake. Also I added a new option if at all you wanted fewer lines of code. Glad I was able to help. Good luck.